# How and why does a nonlinear element produce the sum and difference of two radio frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, frequency, electronics, non-linear-systems

For a resonant circuit the voltages of the capacitive and inductance reactance cancel and the currents of the capacitive and inductance reactance also cancel leading to a zero reactance. Is there a slightly similar explanation of why two frequencies passed though a nonlinear element like a diode produce the sum and difference of the two frequencies?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/698005/

Comment: Is this a case we know that a Taylor series approximates a device with a nonlinear function but we do not know why the device works?  We know the how but not the why.

Answer (score 2):

In very broad strokes,

1. From the Taylor series we know that many nonlinear functions can be approximated by $$f(x)\approx a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +...$$
   For those nonlinear functions where the $a_2$ in the Taylor series is zero (for example because the function is purely antisymmetric), there won't be any frequency doubling.
2. From algebra we know $$(\sin \alpha + \sin \beta)^2=\sin^2\alpha+2\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\sin^2\beta$$
   and from trigonometry,
   $$\sin\alpha\sin\beta=\frac{\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2}$$

Combine those two (with actual knowledge of the system in question) and you get frequency doubling from a wide range of nonlinear systems, whether in electronics, electromagnetics, mechanics, or whatever.

For the case of a diode excited by a voltage signal, the exponential response of the diode is one of the first Taylor series you probably learned, and it has a relatively strong $a_1$ term.

If you excite it with a single frequency, then the $\sin^2$ term, and the constant term in identity $\sin^2\alpha=\frac{1-\cos2\alpha}{2}$ becomes important and explains why diodes are used as RF detectors (producing a DC voltage in response to the RF signal).